# Разобрать json ответ на jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Получаю такой ответ:

```
{
    "key": "value",
    "items": [
    {
        "key2": "value2"
        "keys" {
        "key3": "value3"
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

как получить то, что в items?

---

вот сам код:

```
$.ajax({
                url: content,
                dataType:'json',
                timeout:1000,
                success:function(json){

                    $.each(json, function(i) {              
                        var post = {},
                        element = json.items;

                        post.dt_create = element.published;
                        post.author_link = element.actor.url;
                        post.author_picture = element.image.url;
                        post.post_url = element.url;
                        post.author_name = element.actor.displayName;
                        post.message = element.title;
                        post.description = '';
                        post.social_network = 'google';                                                
                        getTemplate(post);                    
                    });
                }             
            })
```

выходит что element имеет такое: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object].........
как мне данные достать? полный ответ json - http://pastebin.com/ea8VaQRd

Answer (score 4):

Как просили, на jQuery:

```
var json = {
    "key": "value",
    "items": [{
        "key2": "value2",
        "keys": { "key3": "value3" }
    }]
};

var items = jQuery(json).attr('items');
console.log(items);
```

**UPD** Вы совсем не понимаете что делаете, json.items — это [массив](http://javascript.ru/basic/array), заполненный [объектами](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/intro) и что бы получить [свойства](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/intro#dostup-k-svoystvam) published, actor и другие, нужно взять первый элемент массива (судя про примеру), а именно `element = json.items[0]`. Но, так делать нельзя, т.к. завтра, ну может после завтра, порядок элементов в массиве поменяется и ваш код перестанет работать.

Answer (score 2):

Обращаться как к обычным свойствам объектов javascript. 
Если предположить что Ваш ответ находиться в переменной test, то соответственно test.items

Answer (score 1):

У вас json - [объект](http://javascript.ru/Object). json.items - [массив](http://javascript.ru/Array).

```
var elements = json.items;

for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
  var post = {};
  var element = elements[i];
  post.dt_create = element.published;
  post.author_link = element.actor.url;
  post.author_picture = element.image.url;
  post.post_url = element.url;
  post.author_name = element.actor.displayName;
  post.message = element.title;
  post.description = '';
  post.social_network = 'google';                                                
  getTemplate(post);  
}
```

Подробно про объекты можно почитать тут - [Объекты, ООП](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/Object).